# Login Bluehost FTP using Shell Script on Amazon AWS

Tags: shell, ftp, sh

Facing error in script while login FTP on Bluehost server using Shell Script on Amazon AWS.

I am able to login FTP using SSH successfully but when use Shell script to automate the FTP login it shows error LOGIN FAILED.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='HOST IP'
USER='username@domainname.com'
PASSWD='password'
ftp -inv $HOST << EOT
user $USER $PASSWD
EOT
exit 0
```

**Below is the result:**

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 04:11. Server port: 21.
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
331 User username@domainname.com_ OK. Password required
530 Login authentication failed
Login failed.
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "quote USER" and "quote PASS" in your script

```
   #!/bin/sh
    HOST='HOST IP'
    USER='username@domainname.com'
    PASSWD='password'
    ftp -inv $HOST << EOT
    quote USER $LOGIN
    quote PASS $PASSWORD
    EOT
    exit 0
```

i hope help you

Comment: Use "" instead of the one '
USER="username@domainname.com"
PASSWD="password"

May be it considered as belonging to the password.

Comment: I checked using `ftp -invd $HOST << EOF`
Debugging shows correct values are passing.

Comment: use this if you can : ncftp -u $USER -p $PASSWD $HOST << EOT

Answer (score 0):

**This issue may be unique to BlueHost.**

For years I had been successfully using a BASH script with a number of hosting providers for logging in and uploading changes to my SpamAssassin config file. After moving to BlueHost, the script failed, stalled at the password entry prompt, and eventually timed out with a login failure.

The script failed every time even though I was able to successfully login by manually initiating an FTP session and typing/answering the login prompts from a CLI terminal window.

I found the **BlueHost password prompt did not like my script password which included a "$" dollar sign as part of the password**. *The "$" dollar sign embedded in the password was not being passed to the FTP password prompt even when the $PASSWORD variable was quoted as "$PASSWORD".* Changing the password to replace the "$" dollar sign character with another character allowed the script to successfully login and upload.